# How to find the size of the largest doc lib

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to find the document library of which total size (the sum of sizes of its contained documents) is the larges in the farm.

I checked web Analytics --> Inventory --> Storage Usage

But it didn't provide what I need

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question to SharePoint community and I got the below answer and it worked

if you have access to powershell then use this

> ```
> #Get the Site collection
> $Site = Get-SPsite "http://sharepoint.crescent.com"
>
> #Returns a DataTable similar to "Storage Management Page" in Site settings
> $DataTable = $Site.StorageManagementInformation(2,0x11,0,10)
>
> $DataTable | Select Title, ItemCount, Size, Directory | Format-Table
> ```
>
> [Get SharePoint Library Size with PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/01/get-sharepoint-library-size-powershell.html)

[Here it is](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/01/get-sharepoint-library-size-powershell.html)